# React-navigation (v5): How to open bottom-sheet directly on clicking bottom-tab-navigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-bottom-tab

React-navigation (v5): How to open the bottom-sheet directly by clicking on the bottom-tab on the current component (not to open the new component being passed to it)?